# Record just created in Model has null related table instead of empty which breaks my query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a forum where a reply is posted using the following action:

```
var newreply = new ForumReply();

        newreply.ForumPostID = ForumPostID;
        newreply.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        newreply.Reply = Reply;
        newreply.UserID = currentuser;

        db.ForumReply.Add(newreply);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var viewModel = GetPosts(ForumTopicID);

        return PartialView("_forumposts", viewModel);
```

The GetPosts action is as follows:

```
string currentuser = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var topic = db.ForumTopic
            .Where(i => i.ForumTopicID == ForumTopicID && i.Forum.Cohort.enrollment.Any(h => h.UserID == currentuser))
            .Include(s => s.Forum)
            .Include(g => g.Forum.Cohort)
            .Include(f => f.Forum.Cohort.User)
            .Include(w => w.ForumPost.Select(g => g.ForumReply))
            .Single();

        var viewModel = new PostMainViewModel();

        viewModel.Cohortname = topic.Forum.Cohort.Cohortname;
        viewModel.Tutorname = topic.Forum.Cohort.User.Fname + " " + topic.Forum.Cohort.User.Lname;
        viewModel.ForumID = topic.Forum.ForumID;
        viewModel.ForumTitle = topic.Forum.ForumTitle;
        viewModel.ForumTopicID = topic.ForumTopicID;
        viewModel.TopicTitle = topic.TopicTitle;
        viewModel.TopicDescription = topic.TopicDescription;

        var posts = topic.ForumPost
            .OrderBy(h => h.DateCreated)

            .Select(x => new PostViewModel
            {
                ForumPostID = x.ForumPostID,
                Post = x.Post,
                DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
                UserName = x.User.Fname + " " + x.User.Lname,
                Likes = x.ForumPostLike.Count(),
                Isliked = x.ForumPostLike.Any(f => f.UserID == currentuser),
                Usermade = x.UserID == currentuser,
                ProfileImage = x.User.personal?.ProfileImage,

                ReplyViewModel = x.ForumReply
                .Select(y => new ReplyViewModel
                {
                    ForumReplyID = y.ForumReplyID,
                    Reply = y.Reply,
                    DateCreated = y.DateCreated,
                    UserName = y.User.Fname + " " + y.User.Lname,
                    Likes = y.ForumReplyLike.Count(),
                    Isliked = y.ForumReplyLike.Any(f => f.UserID == currentuser),
                    Usermade = y.UserID == currentuser,
                    ProfileImage = y.User.personal?.ProfileImage,

                })

            });

        viewModel.PostViewModel = posts;

        return viewModel;
```

The GetPosts action is used to load the posts/replies on a page and works fine, however when it loads the posts/replies just after a reply as per the above actions, I get a null value error on the ForumReplyLike table of the ForumReplies.  This is because when I create the 'topics' object instead of querying the table fresh it appears to be carrying the ForumReply object that I've just created into the topics object, which means the ForumReplyLike is already null rather than empty going into the query.  That's my understanding of it anyway, it may well be incorrect.

What I want to know is why is this happening and how can I resolve it but still use the same query.  I'm aware I can resolve the actual issue by changing the way I am making the query in the GetPosts action to a couple of foreach loops.  I would like to continue to use the same query action though, which is all directly translate to SQL meaning I can't handle the null in the query using c#.

Would appreciate someone who has a much better grasp than me on such things explaining what is going on here exactly and how I can stop the topics object from being influenced by the forumreply just posted?

edit - I can see I can get around this by disposing my dbcontext and then initialising a new one but presumably there is a better way than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply initialize the `ForumPostLike` property to an empty collection. I guess your current code looks something like that:

```
public virtual ICollection<Something> ForumPostLike { get; set; }
```

That means it will be `null` at object creation. You can initialize it to an empty list in the constructor, or better, if you're using C# 6, you can declare the property this way:

```
public virtual ICollection<Something> ForumPostLike { get; set; } = new List<Something>();
```

Comment: That only works with C# 6. While it's possible the OP is using C# 6, the question is tagged with EF6, so it's more likely they're also still using C# 5.  You should post the older method of ensuring a default value as well.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The posted code in the question contains a null-propagation operator, so C# 6 is being used. And regardless, the way to do it with earlier version is described in my answer ("You can initialize it to an empty list in the constructor").